# How to use include in Chai?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

I'm trying to figure how can I pass an object and just check if the object is in the response using either `that.includes` or `to.include` from chai

I wrote a simple fiddle to check my problem:

<s>https://jsfiddle.net/balexandre/4Loupnjk/2/</s>

https://jsfiddle.net/balexandre/4Loupnjk/5/ with `.deep` flag

```
var e = {
  "results":  {
    "total_rejected_recipients": 0,
    "total_accepted_recipients": 1,
    "id":"102618457586465882"
  }
};
```

from my understanding, the `e` object should actually have the smaller object included... or am I missing something?

```
expect(e).to.include({
  "results":  {
    "total_rejected_recipients": 0,
    "total_accepted_recipients": 1
    }
});
```

but I get the error:

> ```
> assertionError: expected { Object (results) } to have property 'results' of { Object (total_rejected_recipients, total_accepted_recipients) }, but got { Object (total_rejected_recipients, total_accepted_recipients, ...) }
> at Context.<anonymous> (:73:18)
> ```

First time on this framework though, might be the issue :)

Comment: Looks like a bug to me; the temporarily alternative would be using the https://www.npmjs.com/package/chai-subset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should use the `deep.include` assertion, as you have a deep object in there.

Anyways, it looks like this is a bug. The github ticket where this was implemented is located [here](https://github.com/chaijs/chai/pull/761) and the relevant commit [here](https://github.com/chaijs/chai/pull/761/commits/7d1dd301c15f2a72a6e1a248091774b86396f5c9).

The test coverage for this assertion is here:

```
expect({foo: obj1, bar: obj2}).to.deep.include({foo: {a: 1}});
expect({foo: obj1, bar: obj2}).to.deep.include({foo: {a: 1}, bar: {b: 2}});
expect({foo: obj1, bar: obj2}).to.not.deep.include({foo: {a: 9}});
expect({foo: obj1, bar: obj2}).to.not.deep.include({foo: {z: 1}});
expect({foo: obj1, bar: obj2}).to.not.deep.include({baz: {a: 1}});
expect({foo: obj1, bar: obj2}).to.not.deep.include({foo: {a: 1}, bar: {b: 9}});
```

However, it breaks in the following scenario:

```
expect({ foo: obj1, bar: obj2 }).to.deep.include({ foo: { a: 1 }, bar: { } });
```

Better open the issue in [chai](https://github.com/chaijs/chai) repository, and temporary use the [chai-subset](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chai-subset) package.

Comment: created [#983](https://github.com/chaijs/chai/issues/983) as even with `.deep` still throws the same error :( but thanks to point me out what I was leaving behind.